# Span eledmac \edtext over two paragraphs

Tags: paragraphs, eledmac

In `eledmac` is it possible to have an not refer to text spanning two or more paragraphs.

Naturally, this following MWE results in runaway argument error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eledmac}
\begin{document}
\beginnumbering

\pstart
\edtext{Queritur utrum metaphysica sit scientia una.
\pend

\pstart
Et videtur quod non.}{\lemma{queritur \dots{} non}\Afootnote{om. \emph{A}}}
\pend

\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

But would there be any way of creating such a note. Maybe with a different paragraph markup or something?
This is probably a long shot, but I have to give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `\edlabel` + `\xxref` (§9 of handbook)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eledmac}
\begin{document}
\beginnumbering

\pstart
\edlabel{Queritur}Queritur utrum metaphysica sit scientia una.
\pend

\pstart
\edtext{Et videtur quod non\edlabel{non}.}{\xxref{Queritur}{non}\lemma{queritur \dots{} non}\Afootnote{om. \emph{A}}}
\pend

\endnumbering
\end{document}
```